# Categorias de consulta Google

Tags: wordpress, aplicação-web, google

Tenho um site com o wordpress [karanalpe.com.br](http://karanalpe.com.br/). Quando eu realizo uma busca por ele no google é retornado a seguinte informação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando realizo uma consulta para um outro site (terra por exemplo) o mesmo é apresentado de acordo com algumas categorias. Vejamos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As Categorias Terra Mail, Notícias, Esportes e Campeonato Brasileiro possivelmente são as mais acessadas do site. Esse mesmo mecanismo funcionava para o meu site, porém de um tempo para cá deixou de aparecer. Alguém tem ideia do que possa ser?

Comment: Há um plugin para o wordpress que realiza várias otimizações de SEO: https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo.

Comment: Eu utilizo esse plugin Murilo e mesmo assim a consulta do meu site no google não está categorizada. O estranho é que antes ele estava...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você consegue sitelinks através da ferramenta do google WebMasterTools ou No AdWord, também é possível através do robot.txt e arquivos XML (como sitemap).

Para mais informações, segue o link (sobre o AdWord) que sua aparição é instantânea:
https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2375416?hl=pt-BR

Para os demais sites (que não usam o AdWord), existe diversas regras antes de aparecer os sitelinks nos resultados, como: tempo de existência do site, estar no topo do ranking de uma palavra-chave pesquisada, o site ter certe "relevância" de cliques e dentre outros.

Os Algoritmos do Google estão sempre mudando, mas garantir esses aspectos e ter todas funcionalidades garante que algum dia você obterá tal beneficio.

Abraços.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! :)